# Prometheus scrape from Windows - invalid metric name/"INVALID" is not a valid start token

Tags: windows, go, prometheus

I've installed prometheus on my linux node. I have a go application on a Windows server that exports metrics from the app. The metric path for the Windows node is at /app/metrics. Note, the output of the metrics is in json format.

Here is my prometheus.yml:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus_metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter_metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']
  - job_name: 'app-qa-1'
    metrics_path: /app/metrics
    scheme: http
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['app-qa-1:1701']
```

When I query the metrics and pass through the promtool I get:

```
error while linting: text format parsing error in line 1: invalid metric name
```

On my targets page I have this error for the Windows node:

```
"INVALID" is not a valid start token
```

And this is what the metrics from my Windows node look like:

```
"api.engine.gateway.50-percentile": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.75-percentile": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.95-percentile": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.99-percentile": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.999-percentile": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.count": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.fifteen-minute": 0,
"api.engine.gateway.five-minute": 0,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app's metrics aren't in Prometheus' YAML-based [Exposition format](https://github.com/prometheus/docs/blob/master/content/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats.md).

Your best bet is to determine whether the app can be configured to export Prometheus metrics (too).

If not, you're going to need **either** a proxy that sits between your Prometheus server and the app that, when scraped by Prometheus, calls the app's metrics' endpoint and transforms the results into Exposition format.

To my knowledge, there isn't a general-purpose transforming exporter that you can use. But this would be useful. You'd configure it with your endpoints and a transform function and it would do the work for you.

**Or**, you will need to write your own exporter for the app. But, if the current metric list is sufficient for your needs, that may be too much effort.

Comment: Thanks, this helps lead me in the right direction. The app is written in Go. It's on a Windows server but we don't want to enable WMI to export the metrics. So, we're relying on the app to output metrics. I might need to create a transform exporter or see if theres a way to configure my Go app.

Comment: If you can change the app, there's a Golang [library](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/go-application/) for Prometheus that helps instrument the app itself to export Prometheus metrics. Alternatively, you can use the Golang library (or any of the other libraries or none at all*) to write a simple HTTP server that scrapes the app's existing metrics. *- because the exposition format is so straightforward, you don't really even need to use a Prometheus client library, just something that serves HTTP and can output `content-type: text/plain`.